# golang log.Printf crash

Tags: go, crash

Following code crash on my mac after running 2 or 3 seconds, but it's okay on centos 7, and, I am on go 1.6.3.

Questions:

1. What caused such crash?
2. How to avoid it? (Not recover from it)
3. What does arguments of following stack means?

   ```
   log.Printf(0x1068d8, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
   ```

   the signature is:

   ```
   Print(v ...interface{})
   ```

The crashed code:

```
package main
import (
    "log"
)

func main() {
    for {
       log.Printf("hello")
    }
}
```

It will crash in 10 seconds, and prints:

```
2017/09/02 21:50:01 hello
2017/09/02 21:50:01 hello
2017/09/02 21:50:01 hello
2017/09/02 21:50:01 hello
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x1777d0d1d11 pc=0x92f60]

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x12c000, 0x2a)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:547 +0x90 fp=0xc820035da0 sp=0xc820035d88
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/runtime/sigpanic_unix.go:12 +0x5a fp=0xc820035df0 sp=0xc820035da0
sync.(*Pool).Get(0x1991e0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/sync/pool.go:102 +0x40 fp=0xc820035e40 sp=0xc820035df0
fmt.newPrinter(0xed13cae09)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:133 +0x27 fp=0xc820035e80 sp=0xc820035e40
fmt.Sprintf(0x1068d8, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:202 +0x2b fp=0xc820035ed0 sp=0xc820035e80
log.Printf(0x1068d8, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/log/log.go:289 +0x49 fp=0xc820035f20 sp=0xc820035ed0
main.main()
    /Users/haoy/video_projects/rtc-xswitch2/app/recorder/src/test.go:11 +0x3d fp=0xc820035f50 sp=0xc820035f20
runtime.main()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:188 +0x2b0 fp=0xc820035fa0 sp=0xc820035f50
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1 fp=0xc820035fa8 sp=0xc820035fa0
exit status 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[code 0x0b is 11, which is SIGSEGV.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/65pdWIYga4E).

I have seen that error before onMac with Go 1.6.3: see "[go get throws 'fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution'](https://superuser.com/a/1150283/141)".
[Upgrading would be ideal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16585#issuecomment-237303120).

See [go/go issue 17824](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17824) for more, and [cl 32882](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/32882):

> `doc/devel/release.html`: document go1.6.3 doesn't actually support macOS Sierra.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will upgrade my go.